# Invocation of C program in shell

Tags: c

In the [K&R book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) there is a question as following:

> Write a program that converts uppercase to lower and vice versa, depending on the name it is invoked with?

In the solution given, it says that when the program is invoked with the name `lower`, the program converts `lower` to `upper`. In the solution program `argv[0]` is compared with `"lower"` but on Linux `argv[0]` will be `"./lower"` and not `"lower"`.

Could someone clarify that please?

Comment: Then use `argv[1]`. What's the problem?

Comment: I think in their case they don't use the ./ because they set up their shell to use the current directory as a relative path when using executable files. This is similar to the idea of typing only ls and not /usr/bin/ls for example. The ./ in your case specifies that you want to use lower in the current directory. "." means current working directory in *nix systems.

Comment: @uDaY: K&R, or "The C Programing Language" is considered to be *the* resource and book for C programing.

Comment: @uDaY: Sure. Now you know what to look for when you need an authoritative reference on C.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by **authoritative**, and if you believe that C is the same now as it was in the 1970's.

Comment: In the olden days when K&R was written, it was normal to have `.` in your `PATH` environment variable. In modern times, where security is an issue, the `PATH` usually doesn't include `.` (for obvious reasons).

Comment: In the even oldener days, the current directory was searched implicitly, followed by hardcoded `/bin` and `/usr/bin`. There was no `PATH` because environment variables didn't exist yet. It took a long time to get everyone out of the habit of including `.` in `PATH`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  printf("ARGV[0] = %s\n", argv[0]);
}
```

If I compile it as "test_argv", and run it, I get whatever I typed to run the program:

```
% ./test_argv
ARGV[0] = ./test_argv
% test_argv
ARGV[0] = test_argv
% /tmp/test_argv
ARGV[0] = /tmp/test_argv
```

So you want to test the string, for example, against a regular expression, or for a substring.

Comment: If you put the executable in ~/bin/ or somewhere else on your path it will run the executable.

Comment: You can also use `PATH=. test_argv` to set the PATH for just a single command.

Answer (score 3):

How does Shell executes your program? (Very simple explanation below)

```
shell()
{
  loader("Path name/Filename of your program", argv[0], argv[1]...for your program);
}
```

That means all those arguments to the loader, is made by the shell and then the 
loader is invoked and by default argv[0] is made the same as the Path name/File    name of program.

Now when do say ./a.out ..it means absolute path name of your program is ./a.out.(The file a.out in the current directory)

Can we omit ./? The answer is yes, if the environmental variable PATH is having . as one of its component say the first component.

You may see the content of PATH variable by typing echo $PATH in the shell prompt.(A : separated list of paths will be seen).

if . is not there you may add that by typing export PATH=.:$PATH in the shell prompt.

After this you may run your code from the current directory by typing a.out and need not have to type ./a.out.

Now I think this is clear that why  argv[0] becomes the name of the file that you are executing?

**Now can we have a different name for argv[0] and not the filename**?

The answer is yes and then you need to call the loader yourself, that is write a small piece of code that behaves like shell.

You may browse the internet / man page for the **execve** family of functions, which is actually the loader referred here.